CORB blocking google user profile picture
I'm developing a NextJS app with auth.js as authentication manager. Users can only authenticate using Google, Discord, Facebook and GitHub. There's a page in which I need to display the comment made by users. When the page loads up, I can't see the profile pictures of the users (the src attribute of the img tags takes a url, for example https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocInBJXk0p6Nw1ABKwTQ0V-YwfvpM_xHPuLxKNCBvTr9hYJOsA=s96-c).
If I open the dev tools, the console says I have some issues, all releated to this problem. The issue says:
Response was blocked by CORB
and then it specifies the ID of the affected resource, in this case the ID of the image.
After analyzing all the requests made by my app to google, all of them return a 429 Status (too many requests). The tricky thing is that, If I open the image url into another tab on my browser and then reload my app's page, the image will show up, but only the one I opened before.
Is there any solution to this frustrating problem?

just solved the issue: Just add in next.config.js file crossOrigin: "anonymous" and it will approve all the requests
